# AmCharts default axis values

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am building a demographic chart, with age ranges, which is getting the age ranges from the json, the only problem with that is when the values are empty my chart displays nothing, or when there's one or 2 values the blocks are huge and it doesn't show anything for the other ages which I want to show as empty but still visible....

My chart now:

[image]

As you can see it's displaying fine, but I want to show other age ranges which don't have values, is this possible with an option in amcharts?

My json

```
[{"age":"45 - 64","male":-100,"female":50},{"age":"31 - 45","female":50}]
```

My amcharts Javascript

```
$.getJSON('<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>analytic/jobs_demographic_json', function(chartData) {
    AmCharts.makeChart("container2", {
        "type": "serial",
        "theme": "light",
        "rotate": true,
        "marginBottom": 50,

        "dataProvider": chartData,
        "startDuration": 1,
        "graphs": [{
            "fillAlphas": 0.8,
            "lineAlpha": 0.2,
            "type": "column",
            "valueField": "male",
            "title": "Male",
            "labelText": "[[value]]",
            "clustered": false,
            "labelFunction": function(item) {
                return Math.abs(item.values.value);
            },
            "balloonFunction": function(item) {
                return item.category + ": " + Math.abs(item.values.value) + "%";
            }
        }, {
            "fillAlphas": 0.8,
            "lineAlpha": 0.2,
            "type": "column",
            "valueField": "female",
            "title": "Female",
            "labelText": "[[value]]",
            "clustered": false,
            "labelFunction": function(item) {
                return Math.abs(item.values.value);
            },
            "balloonFunction": function(item) {
                return item.category + ": " + Math.abs(item.values.value) + "%";
            }
        }],
        "categoryField": "age",
        "categoryAxis": {
            "gridPosition": "start",
            "gridAlpha": 0.2,
            "axisAlpha": 0
        },
        "valueAxes": [{
            "gridAlpha": 0,
            "ignoreAxisWidth": true,
            "labelFunction": function(value) {
                return Math.abs(value) + '%';
            },
            "guides": [{
                "value": 0,
                "lineAlpha": 0.2
            }]
        }],
        "balloon": {
            "fixedPosition": true
        },
        "chartCursor": {
            "valueBalloonsEnabled": false,
            "cursorAlpha": 0.05,
            "fullWidth": true
        },
        "allLabels": [{
            "text": "Male",
            "x": "28%",
            "y": "97%",
            "bold": true,
            "align": "middle"
        }, {
            "text": "Female",
            "x": "75%",
            "y": "97%",
            "bold": true,
            "align": "middle"
        }],
        "export": {
            "enabled": true
        }

    });
});
```

SO my question, can I predefine the vertical axis with age ranges and then with my values check if the age range matches and append the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`AmCharts.addInitHandler()`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmCharts#addInitHandler) method to pre-process the data (for populating missing categories) before the chart is built.

Below is a working example of how you can solve your particular task.

```js
/**
 * Custom pre-processor for data
 * This will kick in **before** the chart is built
 * We'll manipulate the data to add "missing" categories
 * The category list should be added as an array in `categories` setting
 */
AmCharts.addInitHandler( function( chart ) {

  // is `categories` set?
  if ( typeof chart.categories === "undefined" )
    return;

  // build a new data set
  var data = [];
  for ( var i = 0; i < chart.categories.length; i++ ) {
    data.push( getDataPointByCategory( chart.categories[ i ] ) );
  }

  function getDataPointByCategory( category ) {
    // if we find a category in data, we'll use this data point
    for ( var i = 0; i < chart.dataProvider.length; i++ ) {
      if ( chart.dataProvider[ i ][ chart.categoryField ] == category )
        return chart.dataProvider[ i ];
    }

    // otherwise, we just initialize a new empty datapoint
    var dp = {};
    dp[ chart.categoryField ] = category;
    return dp;
  }
  
  // assign new data
  chart.dataProvider = data;

}, [ "serial" ] );

/**
 * Sample partial data
 */
var chartData = [{
  "age": "45 - 64",
  "male": -100,
  "female": 50
}, {
  "age": "31 - 45",
  "female": 50
}];

/**
 * The chart
 */
AmCharts.makeChart("container2", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "rotate": true,
  "marginBottom": 50,
  "dataProvider": chartData,
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "male",
    "title": "Male",
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "clustered": false,
    "labelFunction": function(item) {
      return Math.abs(item.values.value);
    },
    "balloonFunction": function(item) {
      return item.category + ": " + Math.abs(item.values.value) + "%";
    }
  }, {
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "female",
    "title": "Female",
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "clustered": false,
    "labelFunction": function(item) {
      return Math.abs(item.values.value);
    },
    "balloonFunction": function(item) {
      return item.category + ": " + Math.abs(item.values.value) + "%";
    }
  }],
  "categories": [
    "84+",
    "64 - 84",
    "45 - 64",
    "31 - 45",
    "20 - 31",
    "20 and younger"
  ],
  "categoryField": "age",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "gridAlpha": 0.2,
    "axisAlpha": 0
  },
  "valueAxes": [{
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "ignoreAxisWidth": true,
    "labelFunction": function(value) {
      return Math.abs(value) + '%';
    },
    "guides": [{
      "value": 0,
      "lineAlpha": 0.2
    }]
  }],
  "balloon": {
    "fixedPosition": true
  },
  "chartCursor": {
    "valueBalloonsEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0.05,
    "fullWidth": true
  },
  "allLabels": [{
    "text": "Male",
    "x": "28%",
    "y": "97%",
    "bold": true,
    "align": "middle"
  }, {
    "text": "Female",
    "x": "75%",
    "y": "97%",
    "bold": true,
    "align": "middle"
  }],
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="container2" style="width: 100%; height: 250px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, buddy :)